# org-babel closing RESULTS tag

Tags: org-babel

For a RESULTS in org-babel, is there an option to close it?

For a src block, we have a closing `#+end_src`, but there is no end results type of tag;)

Comment: There is no closing tag for `#+RESULTS:`. You *can* remove results as the answer below shows, except if you use `:results raw`: org-babel does not know where the results end in that case.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the results from evaluating a code block, position the cursor on the code block, and do `M-x org-babel-remove-result`.

```
#+begin_src latex
Hello~world!
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_export latex
Hello~world!
#+end_export
```